# Adding Lightbox Attribute to CQ5 Image Anchor

Tags: adobe, aem, lightbox2

I need to add  `rel="lightbox"` to the anchor tag when you select a target image using either Image or TextImage component. The anchor tag is automatically generated by CQ, but I am unable to find where this happens, or more importantly, if there is a method I can call to add this string.

I am looking over the Adobe documentation for the built-in Image component (http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/Image.html), which I cloned and modified slightly for separate Lightbox use.

Image object has `protected Map<String,String> getImageTagAttributes()`, and I hope there is some equivalent object for anchors in a class that I'm not aware of.

Here is our current Image component that I used for reference.

```
<%@ page import="commons.Doctype,
    wcm.api.components.DropTarget,
    wcm.foundation.Image" %><%
%><%@include file="/apps/site/global.jsp"%><%
String alignment = properties.get("alignment", "");
Image image = new Image(resource);

    //drop target css class = dd prefix + name of the drop target in the edit config
    image.addCssClass(DropTarget.CSS_CLASS_PREFIX + "image");
    if (!alignment.isEmpty() && !alignment.equals("center"))     
    image.addCssClass(alignment);
    image.loadStyleData(currentStyle);
    image.setSelector(".img"); // use image script
    image.setDoctype(Doctype.fromRequest(request));
    // add design information if not default (i.e. for reference paras)
    if (!currentDesign.equals(resourceDesign)) {
        image.setSuffix(currentDesign.getId());
    }
    if (alignment.equals("center")) {
    %><div class="center"><%
    }
    %><% image.draw(out); %><%
    %><cq:text property="jcr:description" placeholder="" tagName="small"/>
    <% if (alignment.equals("center")) {%>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

Right now I'm using jQuery to do the job, but I don't want to rely on scripting if possible.

Comment: This is perhaps a cheesy way to do it, but we solved this problem by avoiding the `<% image.draw(out)%>` call; instead we just emit something like `<img src="<%=image.getSrc()%>"...><a rel="lightbox"...`.

Comment: What about if a target image isn't selected? Do you have a conditional for that? The hyperlink has to wrap round the source image only if a target image is found.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that.  Perhaps the getHref() and getInnerHtml() methods of [DownloadResource](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/DownloadResource.html), from which Image inherits, could be useful?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to extend the image component and use

```
image.addAttribute("rel","lightbox");
```

as per

[Image Class documentation for CQ5.5](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/DownloadResource.html#addAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I just tried it out, but unfortunately I need the `rel` attribute added to the hyperlink around the image, not the image itself.

Comment: Good point. You could change the lightbox to find <a> tags that contain <img rel='lightbox>. It doesn't solve the mystery of where the anchor is being rendered though.

Comment: Another idea; instead of invoking image.draw(out) you could write the output to a Writer, then manipulate it before sending it to out. It seems that the description from the javadoc is "Writes this image as tag to the given writer by invoking the following - calls getImageTagAttributes() - prints the link tag if needed - prints the image tag - prints the attributes - closes the image tag - closes the link tag" so it looks like there's no control over the link. Personally, I feel this would work but potentially be version specific and possibly break if you upgrade CQ.

Comment: I tried manipulating `getImageTagAttributes()` also, but it is a protected class that I cannot access. For now I'm just using jQuery to look for specific classes that the IMG tag has, and getting its parent anchor link value.

Comment: You could subclass the Image class, then you could access the method (assuming it's not Final).

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Sling Rewriters to do that work: http://sling.apache.org/site/rewriting-the-output-through-pipelines.html Basically you can like parse your response and modify it on the fly.